# How to update UI using coroutines after network call

Tags: android, kotlin, variables, try-catch, coroutine

I have a function with a network call using `Dispatchers.IO`, then I want to access and display the value as a `Toast` in my activity, notice that value of `valueVariable` is initialised to an empty string before the try-catch block so as to make it accessible and not scoped, but **even after changing the value, when I call it `withContext` in the main dispatcher I only get an empty string**.

Function:

```
fun calculateDocs() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    var valueVariable = ""
    try {
         db.collection("room1").get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                valueVariable = task.result?.size().toString()
                Log.d("TAG", valueVariable)
            } 
            else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.exception)
            }
         }
         withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
              Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, valueVariable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         }
     } catch(e: Exception) {
         withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using you `addOnCompleteListener` inside a coroutinescope? `addOnCompleteListener` is non blocking and does not need a coroutinescope

Comment: I would also add internally, by default `Firestore`  uses an internal thread pool. Think about using a `suspendCoroutine`. With this the parent dispatcher only needs to be `Main` - it will switch/gauarantee that context when using `resumeWith`

Answer (score 0):

Your `withContext` block gets executed before the network call finishes hence the empty string in `Toast`, there are many ways to fix this but I think use of `LiveData` will require less code change on your end.

to achieve this first you need to define a `LiveData` property in the `class` which contains `calculateDocs` `function`

```
val networkResponse: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

Now in `task.isSuccessful` `if` block post the value to `LiveData`

```
if (task.isSuccessful) {
   valueVariable=task.result?.size().toString()
   Log.d("TAG", valueVariable)
   networkResponse.postValue(valueVariable) // Post value to LiveData
} 
else {
    Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.exception)
}
```

Finally observe this `LiveData` object in your `Activity`

```
networkResponse.observe(this, Observer{
   if(!it.isNullOrEmpty){
      Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to call the suspend function `withContext` from within the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you're using coroutines is pointless, because you don't call any blocking or suspend functions. You are calling an asynchronous API queueing function that has a callback, so it is non-blocking. The code that you want to happen after the asynchronous work is done has to go inside the callback. You can read more about this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value/68370029#68370029). The answers also explain why you have a null response.

One of the main features of coroutines is that you can avoid callback-based code and instead write your code in order from top to bottom, instead of nesting sequentially-later code inside callbacks. However, if you just call synchronous callback-based code in your coroutine, you don't get any of this benefit.

If you want to use a coroutine effectively, you should call suspend function alternatives to the asynchronous callback-based functions. Provided you've imported the `-ktx` version(s) of whatever Firebase library(ies) you're using, there should be a `Task.await()` suspend function that is the coroutine alternative to adding an OnCompleteListener.

Note that you should be using `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope`, and usually you should not need to specify a dispatcher except where you're calling blocking code. The official recommendation from Jetbrains is to use a CoroutineScope that's supplied by your framework (Android Jetpack in this case) and to not change the Dispatcher from the default of `Main` at the `launch` call since it is most convenient to be able to safely call any non-blocking function, and suspend functions don't need dispatchers specified either.

The correct coroutine implementation of your code should look something like this:

```
fun calculateDocs() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val valueVariable = try {
        db.collection("room1").get().await().size().toString()
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", e)
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return@launch
    }
    // Do something with successfully retrieved valueVariable
}
```

If you want to do it without coroutines, take your code out of the `launch` block and move your Toast call inside the callback (without the `withContext` wrapper). The callback will be called on the main thread anyway.